# All logs appear as warnings after uglifying

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, protractor, grunt-contrib-uglify

I use grunt-contrib-uglify to uglify a project. The files have several `console.log`s (and I want them to stay in there).

In my E2E-Tests (with protractor) I check the `browserLog` after every test:

```
expect(browserLog.length).toEqual(0);
```

Those tests worked great before uglifying. Since I uglify the project and test afterwards, `browserLog` isn't empty anymore. It contains all the called `console.log`s (Log-Level: info), but surrounded with some kind of wrapper.

The object looks like that:

```
{
    level: {value:900, name:'WARNING'},
    message: '{"message"{
        "column":14774, ....
        "level":"info"...}}
}
```

What is wrapping my logs so all of them appear as warnings but really aren't?